# Chart X-Axis tick in c3 charts

Tags: javascript, graph, c3.js

I am using C3 bar charts now I am facing problem with X-Axis tick. I am taking value of X-Axis dynamically.

**See below code:**

```
chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#port_range_to_port_range',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x','Ho Chi Minh City', 'Tanjung Priok (Jakarta)', 'Chennai', 'Chennai', 'Chennai'],
            ['Your lowest rate', 530, 800, 900, 525, 190],
            ['Benchmark rate', 241, 890,  254, 100, 149],
            ['Lowest rate on route',200, 859, 256, 365, 410],
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category' // this needed to load string x value
        },
        y: {
            tick: {
                format: d3.format("$,")
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

You can see the above I have used "Chennai" three times in X-axis. See below for more

```
 columns: [
            ['x','Ho Chi Minh City', 'Tanjung Priok (Jakarta)', 'Chennai', 'Chennai', 'Chennai'],
```

So problem is, when graph will plot then these duplicate value is not displaying, This (Chennai) is displaying only one time and rest times its printing the numbers. See attached graph[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/q2spv1mc/1/ Does problem persist?

Comment: I just updated the c3.min.js and its working fine. Previously I was calling from //cdn.jsdelivr.net/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js and now I have downloaded that from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in comments above, since [0.4.11](https://github.com/c3js/c3/releases/tag/0.4.11) c3.js starts to group same categories into one.

Fast workaround is either use previous version, or add extra spaces to category name to make them actually differ but stay visually identical:

```
columns: [['x',
    'Ho Chi Minh City',
    'Tanjung Priok (Jakarta)',
    'Chennai',
    'Chennai ', // <-- here
    'Chennai  ' // <-- and here
],
```

If you want to do it dynamically, more appropriate solution may be **adding index** to repeating categories:

```
columns: [['x', ... some dynamic data ]
    .map(function(category, i, arr){ 
      var prev = arr.slice(0, i); 
      var count = prev.reduce(function(sum, item) { 
        if (item === category) return sum + 1;
        else return sum;
      }, 0); 

      if (count != 0) return category + '-' + count;
      else return category;
    })
]

// will give you 
// [['x', 'Ho Chi Minh City', 'Tanjung Priok (Jakarta)', 
// 'Chennai', 'Chennai-1', 'Chennai-2']]
```

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/q2spv1mc/5/)

Comment: Yes this is I know but in my case all categories coming dynamically from database. So now its working with new c3.min.js. Is there any disadvantage of adding this?

Comment: Disadvantage of being tied to older version is that you miss future bugfixes and other potentially useful updates. And if someone perform (accidentally or by intent) any upgrade, the functionality will break, and such error may be hard to find and fix.

Comment: I updated my answer and fiddle to let the solution apply dynamically. I think it would be better.